# RabbitMQ - parallel processing with strict ordering guarantees

Tags: design-patterns, rabbitmq, amqp, paxos, raft

In HappyFunPizzaCorp we have a POS system which generates two events: `new_order` event and `payment` event. Both events contain a pizza `order_id` key for cross referencing.

Both events are sent to an exchange `TheExchange`. `new_order` events are always emitted before `payment` events.

We are a very busy place, selling, say, 100000 pizzas per second, so processing all of the records serially is not an option.

So the question is how do we parallelize the processing of our workload, while still guaranteeing that `new_order` events are processed before `payment` events for the same pizza?

A simple queue with multiple consumers won't do. We get round-robin behavior between consumers, so it's possible that the `payment` event is processed concurrently with the `new_order` event for the same pizza.

Another solution would be to use a sharded-exchange and use the `order_id` as a sharding key. While that sounds good, we now have some inherent parallelism between queues, how do our consumers connect? We could have a pre-defined set of queues to prevent re-sharding and parallelism between messages because of re-sharding. But then if we have multiple consumer instances, how do they decide which queues to consume data. On top of that, we want to auto-scale our consumers.

Our current solution is to use a consensus protocol (raft/paxos via zookeeper) to determine how many queues and which queues each of the consumer processes should service. We have a pre-set (high number) of sharded queues in the system which should not change. The consumers of the queues are exclusive (giving at most once delivery guarantees) and they coordinate via the consensus protocol which queues should be serviced by whom.

While this set up seems like it will work, it appears to be overly complex, and I am wondering if there is a reference solution which we are missing.

Comment: Is this homework? If not, what is the actual problem you're trying to solve? Why are `payment` events being added to any queue before `new_order` has finished? If `payment` events were added as the last step of `new_order`, the problem is solved.

Comment: It's not homework. It's a problem from work, and I wanted to gather some opinions about the approach.

Comment: For the same order the sequence of events is: `new_order` followed by `payment`. However, the processing of events may take time, and so it is possible that the processing of a payment event overlaps with the processing of a new_order event.

Comment: Still not following - does `payment` correspond to "take my money for order_id X" while `new_order` means "please do order X", and you want to delay taking the money until X is done? If so, the `payment` event should just record the payment information somewhere and that's it. Then `new_order` can fire off a third task, e.g. `process_payment` upon completion. This final task will look up the payment information and do its thing. In this world, you may actually want to have `payment` be a prerequisite for getting starting on `new_order`, or you might be out a bit of cash afterwards.